# Estimate in vanishing viscosity for the difference $\Vert u^\epsilon - u^\eta \Vert_{L^2(\mathbb R^N)} $

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, hyperbolic-pde

Consider the  following advection-diffusion equation
$$
\begin{cases}
u^\epsilon_t + f(u^\epsilon)_x = \epsilon \Delta u^\epsilon\\
u^\epsilon(0,\cdot) = u_0, 
\end{cases}
$$

How can one prove an estimate on the difference
$$\Vert u^\epsilon - u^\eta \Vert_{L^2(\mathbb R^N)} $$
where $u^\epsilon$ solves the advection-diffusion equation
$$
\begin{cases}
u^\epsilon_t + f(u^\epsilon)_x = \epsilon \Delta u^\epsilon\\
u^\epsilon(0,\cdot) = u_0, 
\end{cases}
$$
and $u^\eta$ solves
$$
\begin{cases}
u^\eta_t + f(u^\eta)_x = \eta \Delta u^\eta\\
u^\eta(0,\cdot) = u_0, 
\end{cases}
$$
for the same initial data $u_0$?

Comment: Normally you would square the $L^2$ norm, differentiate in $t$, and use the PDEs to get an inequality, to which you apply Gronwall. Have you tried this kind of approach? Where do you get stuck?